# Is it possible to load Executable once and keep calling it multiple times in Java?

Tags: java

I am working on prototype where in from my Java API I have to run an executable which in C#. There is code which inturn calls Matlab function.
Following is the java code to call the executable(an example)

```
         ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         ByteArrayOutputStream errorStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            
            matProcessWrapper = new ExecWrapper.ExecWrapperBuilder
("C:\\Matlab\\HelloWorld\\bin\\Release\\netcoreapp3.1\\HelloWorld.exe")
            .setErrorStream(errorStream)
            .setOutputStream(outputStream)
            .setTimeOutMilliSeconds(30*1000L)
            .build();
     try {
                matProcessWrapper.executeProcessSync();
    
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The executable is loaded each time. is it possible to load this executable only once and then call its method again and again and once all the calling is done I can exit the model.

Answer (score 1):

You could check if your process wrapper is already loaded or load it in your constructor.

```
public void execute() {
    if (matProcessWrapper == null) {
        loadMatProcessWrapper();
    }
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         ByteArrayOutputStream errorStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        matProcessWrapper.executeProcessSync();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void loadMatProcessWrapper() {
    matProcessWrapper = new ExecWrapper.ExecWrapperBuilder
            ("C:\\Matlab\\HelloWorld\\bin\\Release\\netcoreapp3.1\\HelloWorld.exe")
            .setErrorStream(errorStream)
            .setOutputStream(outputStream)
            .setTimeOutMilliSeconds(30 * 1000L)
            .build();
}
```

Also don't forget to close your streams, I did this in my code snippet with try with resources.

Comment: Hi Milgo, this might sound silly but is it possible me to call the method inside the executable directly when i call it second time? or each time it has to be called this way

Comment: You can't save a Java reference outside of the Java application.